# Angular 2 - Best way to get component's DOM Element in a unit test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I've a sample Angular component template like below:

```
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;">
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
      <a (click)="downloadFile()" class="download-file"><i class="fa fa-download fa-fw"></i>&nbsp;Download</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
      <i [ngClass]="getFileIconClass"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"><strong>Name</strong></div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <span>{{attachment.fileName}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"><strong>Notes</strong></div>
        <div class="col-md-11">
          <span>{{attachment.notes}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

I've to write a unit test to check if the `Name` and `Notes` contain correct value passed in the `attachment` object.

For this purpose I've to get the `HTMLElement`s from the DOM. I need to know what is the best practice to get `HTMLElement` in this case. Should I define a specific Id/Class attribute for each `span` like:

```
...
<span class="fileName">{{attachment.fileName}}</span>
...
<span class="notes">{{attachment.notes}}</span>
...
```

and get `HTMLElement` like:

```
fileNameEl  = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.fileName')); // find span element for fileName
notesEl  = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.notes')); // find span element for notes element
```

or should I just use JavaScript functions (like `parentNode`, `childNodes`, `firstChild`, `nextSibling`, `querySelector` etc) to navigate between nodes.